# How to calculate range of any datatype while casting it

Tags: java, data-structures, logic

For example, a question in my paper came like this

in java: byte's range is -128 to 127

byte x = (byte) 300;

what will be the value of x?

**How can I calculate this thing on paper?**

Comment: fyi, the `(int)` cast does nothing - a integer literal is *already* an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep only the lowest 8 bits, then interpret that as a 2's compliment signed byte.

If using code, you would typically perform a bit-wise AND with `255` (being the value when the lower 8 bits of an `int` are all `1`), ie `300 & 255`, however to calculate this on paper, divide the number by 256 and keep the remainder (in code this would be the modulo operator, ie `300 % 256`) which is your answer, but subtract 256 from the remainder if it's over 127.

In this case, because `300` happens to be in the range `256` to `256 + 127` (ie `383`), you can just do `300 - 256 = 44` and you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets for simplicity look at unsigned bytes (value 0-255) and arbitrary positive integers. When calculating what that integer would be when assigned to a byte, you have to see what the value of that integer is modulo 256. This means that you have to subtract 256 until your number is less than 256.
In your example the integer is 300, and 300 modulo 256 is 44, so 44 would be assigned to an unsigned byte.

Comment: But we're not looking at unsigned bytes. Java's `byte` is signed (which is a pain btw).